# EntityAudit - Doctrine2: Using the same entity in both OneToMany and OneToOne possible

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, auditing

is it possible do audit entities with the simplethings / EntityAudit - https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

using the same entity in both OneToMany and OneToOne relation?

```
    class Address
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column 
         */
        protected $address_text;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="addresses") 
         */
        protected $customer;
    }



    class Customer 
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="customer")
        */
        protected $addresses;

        /**
        * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
        */
        protected $primary_address;
    }
```

without auditing it works perfectly, but with it - the script ends on
`UnitOfWork::getEntityIdentifier` with the "Unidentified index" notice

- described as well on https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit/issues/9
- test case borrowed from [Using the same entity in both OneToMany and OneToOne possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545229/doctrine2-using-the-same-entity-in-both-onetomany-and-onetoone-possible-solve)

Answer (score 1):

1. I've pulled in the changes from https://github.com/merk/EntityAudit/commit/0c1c7df1e53d50629c141b418a18ccee83a3b9b4 , there is also a PR, maybe it's getting fixed in official repo soon ( merk/onetomany branch ).
2. Make also sure your Entity name is written right (Upper/Lowecase) in config.yml, there seems to be no error if its wrong